# CentOS PHP 7.4 Error upgrading pecl / pear packages

Tags: php, centos, centos7, pear, pecl

**CentOS 7.6**

I've ran through this same process on 5.x versions and 7.2 without issue, but some pear/pecl steps are failing in 7.4 as I'm attempting an upgrade migration from 7.2 right now.

During the provisioning process I am running a timezonedb upgrade from pecl and hitting an error:

```
[root@d9471f6a1ab2 /]# pear upgrade -c pecl.php.net timezonedb
downloading timezonedb-2019.3.tgz ...
Starting to download timezonedb-2019.3.tgz (413,166 bytes)
....................................................................................done: 413,166 bytes
5 source files, building
running: phpize
Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

So naturally I attempt to install the package it asked for `php-devel` however it attempts to downgrade some of my existing packages back to php5.4!

```
yum install php-devel 
...
Error: php73-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
Error: php73-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64
```

My normal procedure for building out a php runtime includes installing `timezonedb` pecl package and upgrading it during the provisioning process. This process hasn't changed much on all previous PHP upgrades, but I'm having some trouble on php7.4

> The **full package list** is included below, but most importantly, I have the following installed:
>
> `php74-php-pear`
>
> `php74-php-devel`

Here is the output of `yum list installed php*`

```
[root@d9471f6a1ab2 /]# yum list installed php*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fileplanet.com
 * epel: mirror.prgmr.com
 * extras: mirror.hostduplex.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: repos.lax.quadranet.com
Installed Packages
php-cli.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                   5.4.16-46.1.el7_7                                                                                                                                                        @updates  
php-common.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                5.4.16-46.1.el7_7                                                                                                                                                        @updates  
php-devel.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                 5.4.16-46.1.el7_7                                                                                                                                                        @updates  
php74-php-bcmath.x86_64                                                                                                                                                          7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-cli.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-common.x86_64                                                                                                                                                          7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-devel.x86_64                                                                                                                                                           7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-fpm.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-gd.x86_64                                                                                                                                                              7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-intl.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-json.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-mbstring.x86_64                                                                                                                                                        7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-opcache.x86_64                                                                                                                                                         7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-pdo.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-pear.noarch                                                                                                                                                            1:1.10.10-4.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                     @remi-safe
php74-php-pecl-geoip.x86_64                                                                                                                                                      1.1.1-11.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                        @remi-safe
php74-php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64                                                                                                                                                   3.1.0-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-pecl-imagick.x86_64                                                                                                                                                    3.4.4-6.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-pecl-msgpack.x86_64                                                                                                                                                    2.1.0~beta1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                   @remi-safe
php74-php-pecl-redis5.x86_64                                                                                                                                                     5.1.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64                                                                                                                                                     2.9.0-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-pecl-zip.x86_64                                                                                                                                                        1.15.5-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                        @remi-safe
php74-php-pgsql.x86_64                                                                                                                                                           7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-process.x86_64                                                                                                                                                         7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-soap.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-php-xml.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             7.4.1-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                         @remi-safe
php74-runtime.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             1.0-1.el7.remi                                                                                                                                                           @remi-safe
```

Here are my repos:

```
 * base: mirror.fileplanet.com
 * epel: mirror.prgmr.com
 * extras: mirror.hostduplex.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: repos.lax.quadranet.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1/ `timezonedb` extension is NOT useful.**

RPM packages use the system `tzdata`, which is updated separately.

**2/ you are confused with package names**

- `php74-php-*` packages are Software Collections designed for parallel
  installation of multiples verson
- `php-*` packages are simpler to use as single / default version

As explained in the [FAQ](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl), and if you follow the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

**3/ don't need to build from sources**

most useful extensions are available as binary packages, see the [full list](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status)

**4/ symlinks and environment**

If you really prefer the SCL packages (php74-php-*), you can simply set the environment using the command

```
module load php74
```

As SCL are designed for multiples versions, this allow to switch from one version to another

And if you want to make a collection the default one, you can install the `php74-syspaths` packages

But again, simpler to use the `php-*` packages

Comment: So I just read the pages you sent from the Remi site. It sounds like `yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73` is what I need, then I can just use the `php-` packages? Not sure why I didn't have to mess with this with php72 as I did a very similar scenario and did the `php72u-*` pkgs. Oh well. Thanks for the help

Comment: and what about Apache httpd mod_php? I don't use php-fpm service - so, how apache will choose new php module after restart?

Comment: If you have a single version mod_php can be installed / used.
If you have multiple versions, you have to use php-fpm.

Comment: Read https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Updated Solution**

Below is my original solution. However the root issue here is that the remi install for some reason doesn't add anything to the $PATH when yum is used to install the packages.

It installs things into `/opt/remi/php74/` and then its up to you to update your environment variables.

There is an environment source file left over as a **hint** on what to do:

```
bash-4.2$ cat /opt/remi/php74/enable 
export PATH=/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/bin:/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/sbin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export MANPATH=/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/share/man:${MANPATH}
```

In my case I was using docker, so I added to my Dockerfile:

```
ENV PATH="/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/bin:/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/sbin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}"
ENV MANPATH="/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/share/man:${MANPATH}"
```

After that, everything works! So the environment variables are all that was needed. You could use rc.local, /etc/environment, etc to update your environment with them.

### ------

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION:**

Ended up resolving with the following:

Ensure we have most recent repos:

```
yum -y install \
    https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
    https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm \
    https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm \
    http://mirrors.mediatemple.net/remi/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

Then, at minimum, install `php74-php-pear` and `php74-php-devel` (I needed to install WAY MORE libs, but I believe these are all that's required)

Link the pear that remi installed. Not sure why this didn't take place in the first place:

```
ln -sf /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/bin/pear /usr/bin/pear
```

Then I was able to do what I needed to do:

```
pear channel-update pecl.php.net 
pear upgrade -c pecl.php.net timezonedb
```

Worked successfully.

- I think the issue was I was running the wrong version of pear and the newly installed version didn't get added to the path. Creating the link to a path dir solved the problem.
- You could also edit the $PATH but this worked better for my scenario.